# rack-pjax isn't recognizing `jQuery ->`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, pjax

In the `application.js` file, I have the requirements, and the on JQuery declaration:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require jquery.pjax
//= require_tree .

jQuery ->
  $('#id').pjax('[data-pjax-container]')
```

However, I am getting the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token >` in the console.   The `jquery.ja` and `jquery.pjax.js` files are loading in the resources and network tab of the inspector, so i know it is at least getting the jquery and pjax.jquery code, however, the shortcut `` `jQuery -> `` to signify document.ready, throws the error.

When I switch the code to :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#ce').pjax('[data-pjax-container]')
});
```

I don't get the error.   What is the correct shortcut for document.ready in Rails?   I was following the PJAX tutorial [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/294-playing-with-pjax) that says to use this notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What your are typing is Coffeescript syntax, that's the reason why its a syntax error.

Comment: possible to manually turn turn `application.js` into `application.js.coffee` without other repercussions?

Comment: I think its possible. You can always try it out yourself.

Comment: I did, I was referring to other unknown repercussion, as the `application.js` is the only non-coffee script generated by rails

Comment: I think it should be fine.